# Exporting EVI image on Google Earth Engine with visual parameters between -1 and 1?

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, ndvi, landsat, evi

I am having an issue with exporting an EVI image with the visual parameters between -1 and 1. On Google Earth Engine (GEE), using the inspector tool, the values are between -1 and 1, but when I export and upload onto Arcmap, the values exceed that threshold to something like -300 to 800. This isn't an issue with the NDVI.

```
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T2_TOA/LC08_097055_20180301');

var evi = image.expression(
    '2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1))', {
      'NIR': image.select('B5'),
      'RED': image.select('B4'),
      'BLUE': image.select('B2')
});
    
 
Map.centerObject(image, 9);

var eviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};

Map.addLayer(evi, eviParams, 'EVI image');

Export.image.toDrive({

  image: evi.visualize(eviParams), //I have tried solely with **evi** and that doesn't work either

  description: 'EVIex',

  scale: 30,

  region: geometry

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the script you added, indeed using `image: evi.visualize(eviParams)` will give you an RGB image with high values. Just use `image: evi` and it should work, at least it worked for me.

You can try to export the file as EE Asset and open it in Google Earth Engine. Might be easier to analyse this way.